# building QT (2009.04) with VS2008 (on XP)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt

Has anyone managed to build the latest QT (2009.04) with VS2008?

I am having problems building QT

I configured QT by running this command:

```
C:\Qt\2009.04\qt>configure -no-sql-sqlite -no-qt3support -no-opengl -platform win32-msvc2008 -no-libtiff -no-dbus -no-phonon  -no-phonon-backend -no-webkit
```

When I run nmake, this was the output (just before the error)

```
.\tokenizer.cpp(477) : warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be
 unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECUR
E_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        c:\VisualStudio_9.0\VC\INCLUDE\string.h(74) : see declaration of 'strcpy
'
.\tokenizer.cpp(560) : warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be
 unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECUR
E_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        c:\VisualStudio_9.0\VC\INCLUDE\string.h(74) : see declaration of 'strcpy
'
.\tokenizer.cpp(561) : warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be
 unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECUR
E_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        c:\VisualStudio_9.0\VC\INCLUDE\string.h(74) : see declaration of 'strcpy
'
tree.cpp
uncompressor.cpp
webxmlgenerator.cpp
.\webxmlgenerator.cpp(134) : warning C4065: switch statement contains 'default'
but no 'case' labels
yyindent.cpp
Generating Code...
        link /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\2009.04\qt\lib" /LIBPATH:"c:\Qt\2009.04\qt\lib" /NO
LOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"tmp\obj\release
_shared\qdoc3.intermediate.manifest" /OUT:release\qdoc3.exe @C:\DOCUME~1\NEILOS~
1\LOCALS~1\Temp\nm194F.tmp
        mt.exe -nologo -manifest "tmp\obj\release_shared\qdoc3.intermediate.mani
fest" -outputresource:release\qdoc3.exe;1
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Has anyone managed to build QT on XP with VS2008 ?

Comment: Is it an error, or a warning? Did QT finished building?

These warnings are due to Visual Studio trying to harden their software against security leaks because of possibile exploits with strcpy, and come up with a strcpy_s (where s might stands for secure). This, unfortunately, is in the C++ standard.

Comment: Sorry, I have ebeen away from my desk. It does indeed look like the build completed succesfully (I expected the build to take 4 hours or more - from the posts I had read online - so since it only took about 30 mins, I assumed the build failed - especially, since it had failed previously, with another configuration [config options])

Answer (score 1):

The messages you have seem to be only warnings. Visual Studio advises you to use safe function from Windows instead of unsafe standard ones (strcpy_s instead of strcpy). For Qt, you can disable C4996 warnings in order to not have these message.

Anyway if you have problems compiling Qt or if you do not want to compile Qt before using it, you can download Qt binaries (.dll & .lib) for Visual Studio 2008 here : http://qt.developpez.com/binaires/en/.

Answer (score 0):

You can but your steps to build Qt files in a batch file and call it even from your favorite text editor, to do this please see this article:
http://msoos.wordpress.com/2009/11/28/building-qt-applications-using-your-favorite-text-editor/

or you can use QtNpp plugin (Qt Notepad++ plugin) to build Qt files from inside Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

You can see on their [labs blog](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/11/17/qt-460-release-candidate-1/) that starting with Qt 4.6 Release Candidate 1 they provide VS2008 precompiled binaries for the open source edition so you will not need to recompile them yourself or get them from 3rd parties.

From the comments:

> Yes, we intend to release both mingw and vs2008 binary packages for as long as those compilers are in our list of “Tier 1″ platforms.